# android gdx sound performance issue

Tags: android, performance, audio, libgdx

I'm building a scrolling shooter with libgdx. in windows, everything runs just fine, but on android i get noticeable jitter and the framerate drops from 61 fps avg without sound to 48-56 fps avg with sound. it plays a lot of small sound effects concurrently as there are a lot of bullets to fire and enemies to hit at once. my sound routine:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;

public class SoundFX {

    static final int BGDIE = 1, BGHIT = 2, BGLASER = 3, BGSPAWN = 4, PDIE = 5, PHIT = 6, PLASER = 7, PSPAWN = 8, PAUSE = 9;
    Sound S_BGDIE, S_BGHIT, S_BGLASER, S_BGSPAWN, S_PDIE, S_PHIT, S_PLASER, S_PSPAWN, S_PAUSE;

    public void load()
    {
        S_BGDIE = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/badguydie.mp3"));
        S_BGHIT = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/badguygothit.mp3"));
        S_BGLASER = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/badguylaser.mp3"));
        S_BGSPAWN = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/badguyspawn.mp3"));
        S_PDIE = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/playerdie.mp3"));
        S_PHIT = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/playergothit.mp3"));
        S_PLASER = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/playerlaser.mp3"));
        S_PSPAWN = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/playerspawn.mp3"));
        S_PAUSE = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sfx/pause.mp3"));
    }

    public void unload()
    {
        S_BGDIE.dispose();
        S_BGHIT.dispose();
        S_BGLASER.dispose();
        S_BGSPAWN.dispose();
        S_PDIE.dispose();
        S_PHIT.dispose();
        S_PLASER.dispose();
        S_PSPAWN.dispose();
        S_PAUSE.dispose();
    }

    public void play(int id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
        case BGDIE:
            S_BGDIE.play();
            break;
        case BGHIT:
            S_BGHIT.play();
            break;
        case BGLASER:
            S_BGLASER.play();
            break;
        case BGSPAWN:
            S_BGSPAWN.play();
            break;
        case PDIE:
            S_PDIE.play();
            break;
        case PHIT:
            S_PHIT.play();
            break;
        case PLASER:
            S_PLASER.play();
            break;
        case PSPAWN:
            S_PSPAWN.play();
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            S_PAUSE.play();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalid sfx call");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

play gets called roughly 4-10 times a second depending on what's happening in the game, the sound effects are less than a second in duration and on avarage 8kb each.

what's going on here, and how can i fix this? it makes the game look very unprofessional and on hard levels almost unplayable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little background into the problem about why you notice such a big drop in performance when playing multiple sounds. This is because underneath the covers libgdx needs to mix the sounds together before playing them back to the user. When you get to a certain number of sounds running concurrently the demands on the system to do the mixing becomes noticeably high. Since you are likely trying the play sounds on the rendering thread this increase in demand results in a drop in framerate.

In my experience with any sort of sound effects in games, when you encounter a situation where you have a lot of small sounds playing concurrently there are few solutions. I will write these as more general solutions than specifics for libGDX:

1) **Play all sounds on a single thread**

This is what you are currently doing, while it doesn't work well once a large number of sounds playing it is easy to implement and for most situations it works. However, once you get enough sounds playing together you will notice lag and poor quality.

2) **Play sounds on a separate thread from the rendering thread**

This is one possible approach (and depending on if the framework allows), its not very good because it doesn't scale well. However, if you are only suffering minor performance loss and aren't expecting to play a huge number (~20+) of sounds concurrently this is a relatively minor change and will usually fix the problem.

3) **Play sounds upto a cap**

This solution is a bit more work, and may not be acceptable if you have sounds which must be played. You simply track the number of sounds playing and allow for additional sounds to be played until you hit a certain point. Anything above the cap is simply not played. This allows you to guarantee a certain level of performance. The biggest downside to this method is if you play a sound when your character is critically injured and it doesn't get played, then this may upset the user as they could be listening for the sound to know if they are going to die soon, but instead find themselves dead.

4) **Selectively play important sounds**

This is a bit more difficult to implement but it works extremely well as you are essentially setting a cap on performance. What you would want to do is determine the priority for a sound to be played. Is it close to you? Is it loud? Is it important? Then, you only play sounds which are important enough to play upto a certain cap (could be 4, 6, 8, etc). You would also need to keep track of how many sounds are currently playing to determine how many new sounds you can play at a given point.

Comment: thanks! very extensive answer. now i know where to look and how to solve it. i'm first going to see if putting a cap on concurrent sounds solves the problem. if it does, i'm going to add sound priorities. if it doesn't, i'm going to use a separate sound thread with a lower priority.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around: the sounds that are less important to be played to the player, you can play them only if the current FPS is above a certain value. For example:

```
if (Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond() > 56) playSound();
```

And important sounds should always be played, no matter the FPS value.